# Why I'm getting this RegEx grouping?

Tags: java, regex

I coded this RegEx to extract e-mails:

```
(\w+)\s*(?:@|(at)|(\s*at\s*)|(\(at\)))\s*((\w+)(?:\.|\s*dot\s*)(\w+)*(?:\.|\s*dot\s*)*)+com
```

My requirements are domain names could come in two shapes: domain.com or sub.domain.com

Running it show that the total group count is 7

For:
 user@domain.com
Group 0, user@domain.com
Group 1, user
Group 2, null
Group 3, null
Group 4, null
Group 5, domain.
Group 6, domain

Why I'm getting this "clustering"? All what I want is to extract the username and the domain.

Comment: Because that's what `()`s do. If all you want is the username and the domain, why not just use `String#split()`?

Comment: split on what? I could have @|at|(at) and dot|.

Comment: Split on `@`, and, assuming there are only 2 resultant parts, split the second part on `.` (period).

Answer (score 0):

Each parenthesis couple adds a new group in your pattern. Simply you don't need all of them.
I have tried this expression:

```
(\w+[\.\w+]*)\s*(?:@|at|\s*at\s*|\(at\))\s*(\w+(?:\.|\s*dot\s*)\w+*(?:\.|\s*dot\s*)*)+com
```

It matches correctly:

```
john.smith@sub.domain.com
\1: john.smith
\2: sub.domain

john.smith@domain.com
\1: john.smith
\2: domain
```

and

```
johnsmith@domain.com
\1: johnsmith
\2: domain
```

Comment: Even non-capturing groups are going to effect group count?

Comment: Your RegEx generates an error java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 65

Comment: Also, note that the `\s*at\s*` in your regex is redundant - this is handled by the `at` in combination with the `\s*` surrounding the regex for `(?:@|at|...)`.

Comment: @Chiron that's because of the `\w+*` (which, while valid, makes no sense in your original regex anyway). Try `\w+` or `\w*` depending on what behaviour you want.